# Python kernel dies when using numba overload

Tags: python, jit, numba

I am attempting to use an externally defined function inside of a numba jitted function, through use of numba's overload [(docs here)](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/extending/overloading-guide.html) but the Python kernel dies when I run it. Here is my minimal example to reproduce:

```
from numpy.polynomial.legendre import leggauss as lg  # My externally defined function
import numba as nb
from numba.extending import overload

@overload(lg)
def implimentlg(n):
   if not isinstance(n, (int, nb.types.Integer, nb.int32)):
      raise nb.errors.TypingError("must be int")

   def impli(n):
      return lg(n)
   return impli

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def tmp():
   return lg(15)

tmp()
```

I would guess my problem has something to do with the typing in my `implimentlg` function, but without a stack trace I am at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was running my python code in a iPython terminal using the neovim package "nvim-ipy". Running my code directly instead with `python3 myFile.py` gave a stack trace.